# Oracle order by descending with NULL last

Tags: sql, oracle

my objective is, to print the result of the query in "DESCENDING" order. but the problem is, the rows with NULL values went on top of the list.. how to put the null rows at the bottom, if the order by is descending?

```
select mysubcat.subcat
       , mysubcat.subcatid as subcat_id
       , (select SUM(myad.PAGEVIEW) 
           from myad 
            where MYAD.CREATEDDATE between  '01-JUL-13 02.00.49.000000000 PM' and '13-JUL-13 02.00.49.000000000 PM'
            AND MYAD.status = 1 
            and  MYAD.mobileapp IS NULL
            and myad.subcatid = mysubcat.subcatid )as web_views 
from mysubcat 
order by web_views desc;
```

the sample result goes like this

```
                             SUBCAT_ID    WEB_VIEWS
Swimming Lessons                56        (null)    
Medical Services                17        (null)
Mobile Phones & Tablets         39        6519
Home Furnishing & Renovation   109        4519
```

the order is in the descending order, I just want to put the rows with null values at the bottom of the printed result, so how?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `DESC NULLS LAST` to achieve that.

Here is the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html) from Oracle.

> **NULLS LAST**
>
> Specifies that NULL values should be returned after non-NULL values.

Comment: @sasori - but it would have been even faster for you to have read the documentation yourself.

Comment: @APC That appears to be the documentation for "JavaDB", not the Oracle database. It does happen to be the same in this case, but [Oracle's actual documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2171079) tends to be rather impenetrable. [PSOUG](http://psoug.org/reference/orderby.html) tends to be more helpful, but even they're pretty verbose at times.

Comment: @jpmc26 - PSOUG has been in decline since Dan Morgan stopped maintaining it.  For up-to-date stuff you should use his new sight: http://www.morganslibrary.org/library.html

Comment: @APC That may not be true if you're still on Oracle 10g like my client. (They're currently in the process of upgrading to 11g.)

Answer (score 7):

Use a  `case`

```
order by case when web_views is not null 
              then 1 
              else 2 
         end asc, 
         web_views desc;
```

Comment: thanks , I'll choose the first answer as the best though, coz it doesn't require any conditional statement to achieve the goal

Comment: +1 . . . I prefer this version because it works in more databases.

Comment: You saved my and my collegues day!